# SNMP v3 gets with SnmpSharpNet and AES192/AES256

Tags: snmp, snmpsharpnet

I'm trying to use SnmpSharpNet to make and SNMP v3 get with a privacy algorithm of AES192 or AES256.

I cannot get a positive response back.  I do for AES128 and DES though.

I noticed in iReasoning MIB Browser tool there is an option (checkbox) labeled: "AES192/256 Key expansion with engine ID”

I'm betting that is the piece I'm missing.  Does anyone know how to configure SnmpSharpNet to do this for AES192 or AES256?

This is how I'm setting up my SecureAgentParameters.  Which works fine with PrivacyProtocols.AES128 and PrivacyProtocols.DES.

```
            param.authPriv (
                "admin",
                AuthenticationDigests.MD5, @"12345678@",
                PrivacyProtocols.AES256, @"12345678@");
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Last time when I discussed with the author of SNMP#NET, he used snmp4j test agent to validate the product. So when you say AES192 and AES256 do not work, you should provide more details on how you get the error.

Comment: I'm sure it is something I have to do with the configuration.  I get a SnmpSharpNet.SnmpException (Message=Request has reached maximum retries.) when I do a request.  (SnmpV3Packet)target.Request (pdu, param);  I am in contact with the device's manufacturer and they said they test that encryption with iReasoning MIB Browsers with that checkbox unchecked.

Comment: "Request has reached maximum retries." is an interesting message. If possible, locate the portion of code in SNMP#NET, and also capture network packets. The two should give you more hints on how to understand the issue, and you should be able to see exactly what is the error pattern.